# ASP.NET Boilerplate Angular compile errors

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

After download of a fresh version of ABP you run these commands in the angular project folder:

```
npm install 
npm start
```

...but then the nightmare starts:

- deprecated @types/moment@2.13.0
- deprecated @types/moments-timezone@0.5.30
- deprecated request@2.88.2
- deprecated fsevents@1.2.13
- deprecated har-valiators@5.1.5

What is the strategy to get this all fixed and running smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

```
yarn install
npm start
```

gives way better results and a running application!